# Immutable class in java changing value causing issue

Tags: java

```
// An immutable class
public final class Student {
    final String name;
    final int regNo;

    public Student(String name, int regNo) {
        this.name = name;
        this.regNo = regNo;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getRegNo() {
        return regNo;
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Student s = new Student("ABC", 101);
        System.out.println(s.name);
        System.out.println(s.regNo);


        // Case 1 :: s.regNo = 102; It will throw exception because we can't change the final value
        // Case 2 ::

        String s = "test"; // String immutable class so as per above class if I try to change the value of s then it should also causing issue or throw exception
        But it will not throw any exception.

        String s = "test1"; // It will not throw any exception but in case 1 it will throw exception        

    }
}
```

Need to understand Case1 and Case2. Please help in out.

> My question is that String is immutable class. So if we changed the
>   string value then it will create other object but if we create our own
>   Immutable class then we are not able to change the value once we
>   assign the value due to the final variable.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with immutability of the class. You create an instance of the class, then immediately shadow it by creating a string variable with the same name, then create another variable with the same name. You haven't changed any of the objects involved.

Answer (score 0):

`String` is an immutable class meaning there's no way[*] to change the value of a given string object. When you assign `s1 = "test"` you're assigning a **different** object to the same variable. This is analogous to doing `s = new Student("new name", 123)`.

Of course, you could also define `s` as `final` to prevent re-assignment to it, but that's regardless of the fact that `s`'s type is immutable.

[*] At least on "proper" way, without resorting to reflection, byte-code manipulation and other "underhanded" techniques

Answer (score 0):

incase case 2 , your string variable **s** is not final hence you can assign a different value to it. 
you will get same error like case 1 if you make it like  `final String s = "test";`